# Delete Temp Files and Empty Recycle Bin_Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, popen

Was wondering if someone could help critic this code I put together.

It is suppose to delete all temp files and folders and then empty the recycle bin.

I had to make some adjustments because using Pyinstaller, and I wanted the console to stay open and have the user proceed after reading.

```
import os
file_size = os.path.getsize('C:\Windows\Temp')
print(str(file_size) + "kb of data will be removed")
import os, subprocess
del_dir = r'c:\windows\temp'
pObj = subprocess.Popen('rmdir /S /Q %s' % del_dir, shell=True, stdout = 
subprocess.PIPE, stderr= subprocess.PIPE)
rTup = pObj.communicate()
rCod = pObj.returncode
if rCod == 0:
    print('Success: Cleaned Windows Temp Folder')
else:
    print('Fail: Unable to Clean Windows Temp Folder')
import winshell
winshell.recycle_bin().empty(confirm=False, show_progress=False, 
sound=False)
from random import randint
from time import sleep
sleep(randint(4,6))
input("Press any key to continue")
```

Comment: Welcome!
Please use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the following modules from the standard library :

- `shutil` that provides high level operations on filesystems (remove tree, etc).
  https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/shutil.html#module-shutil
- `tempfile` provides a better handling on temporary files. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tempfile.html#module-tempfile
- `atexit` provides a registry of functions that are executed before exiting the Python interpreter whatever's the reason. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/atexit.html?highlight=atexit#module-atexit